# Database for exercises

Tags: database, mobile

Am trying to create an application that has a database of all common exercises. am looking for an API or a resource on-line to get this infomration. any recommendations ?

Comment: I'd say Google. This is not the place to get the codez.

Answer (score 0):

you should check http://cloudbase.io. It has a free version that you can use for your project.